# Background not visible on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, background

Can somebody tell me why when I open this website template with Chrome from Android I cannot see the background?

https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/highlights/

If I open the same link with Firefox for Android, the background shows up with no problems (everything is also fine with all browsers from the PC). I tried changing the CSS in a zillion ways, but I still got the issue. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Tested in browserstack. No issues.

Comment: clean your browser history to clean cached data, try again

Comment: @Alejalapeno it has issues if you open it from Chrome Android, not if you simulate it from PC.

Comment: @muratkh the browser cache is of course clean, that is not the problem.